# if X not finite then O is not a $\sigma$ - algebra

Tags: measure-theory

let O (family of sets) consist of those sets which are either finite or have a finite complement. then O is an algebra. I did this part!

my question now is:

if X (space) is not finite, then O is not a $\sigma$ - algebra.

The definitions of algebra and $\sigma$ - algebra are clear to me. For the first part of the question it didn't matter whether X was finite, because if it wasn't then $X^{c}$ would, and therefore would be included in O. And since $\sigma$ - algebra differ from algebra in that we have closure under countable unions, I assume that I have to look there. But I am not sure how to go abut it.

Any sorts of tip would be great, thank you very much.

Comment: So, what kind of set does _not_ belong to O?

Comment: I'd say one that is infinite in size

Comment: And what about its complement?

Comment: ah, in the case when both the set and it's complement are not finite, right?

Comment: Right. And now take a countably infinite set with infinite complement (or an infinite set with countably infinite complement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $X$ contains a countable subset with an infinite complement.